# How to view objects with a subsurf modifier more simply?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I am doing [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNbAmJ3eubo) tutorial. From about 16:00 till 21:00 min he is modelling the first part of the screen resulting in this:

[image]

When doing this his viewport in right view looks very simple and more handy than mine:

[image]

When I am in right view my screen looks like this. How can I get that same viewport view ?

And ... I really have great difficulties to follow this tutorial from 16:00 - 21:00 min ... but would like to get it done. Ideas ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check 'Optimal Display' on the subsurf modifier to simplify the view to not show the new subsurf faces:

[image]

This has to be done on *every* object you want to view simplified. You can do this by hand or by selecting all the objects you want to enable 'Optimal Display' on, enabling 'Optimal Display' on one of them and then right clicking on 'Optimal Display' and choosing 'Copy To Selected'.

Comment: I checked optimal display but still a rather complex view, and not close to the view in the tutorial ?

Comment: It may be helpful if you can upload your file and add it to your question using a service like http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ . Comment back here when you have done so and I will look. Also, I would suggest not marking an answer as correct before checking it works for you.

Comment: To me it looks like that other object is separate. You need to enable 'Optimal Display' on each object that you wish to view simplified.

Comment: You can also bring down the number of subdivisions on the view option of the modifier.

Comment: @ray marliot I did upload My blendfile

Comment: Enabling 'Optimal Display' on *both* objects simplifies the view for me. The only other reason it might look slightly different to the tutorial is if you have added more edges to the mesh than they did.

Comment: @ray marliot  I really try to follow Up to all the rules and expectations of this site. And yes, I still have Some learning points

Comment: You are right. I will make it my habit to set Optimal Display for Subsurf modifier :)